# Question sorting controls disappear when there are either 1 or 2 questions on the last page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, pagination, question-lists

See the recent, views, newest and votes sort buttons on the profile pages:

[Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9):

[image]

---

[Joel Coehoorn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn):

[image]

---

[Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood):

[image]

---

This can also be repro'd on other Trilogy sites. In fact, even [Mr. Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) is not immune.

Comment: [http://i.imgur.com/f057e.png](http://i.imgur.com/f057e.png) <- Happens on Answers as well, though much rarer since those are arranged in groups of 30 compared to 10 for answers. Snapshot comes from [Kyle Cronin](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/658/kyle-cronin), and you can check [Welbog](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/52443/the-proposer) to see that it also happens for 2.

Comment: Took a while but I finally found someone with 93 answers, [Rosinante](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138822/rosinante), and that still has the sorting. So it's exactly the same as with questions - sort controls disappear with 1 or 2 on the last page.

Comment: Wow, that's bizarre. Must be a common paging algorithm or something. @Gra

Comment: They also don't appear for users that have < 3 questions/answers in total. I'm betting on a web service trying to remove cruft for users with a trivial # of posts, and not taking the page # into account...

Comment: @Grace, can I assume you uploaded [http://imgur.com/Djxbl.png](http://imgur.com/Djxbl.png) yourself, without the Stack Exchange pro account? (So, without the button in the editor?) If not, then please see [Is imgur losing images?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75105/is-imgur-losing-images/75143#75143)

Comment: @Arjan The Stack Exchange account didn't exist at the time this bug report was made, so yes, I uploaded it myself. I can reupload it later today.

Comment: (I have a screencapture of answers in my post as well, so no worries, @Grace.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, it was a counting error.

We **intentionally** hide the controls when there are very few questions/answers, there's no need to sort 2 or fewer items we feel (we trust most users are smart cookies!).

However, it *was* using the *page count* rather than the *total count* when determining this...in the next build (today or tonight) this will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Like noted in the comments, this indeed also applies to answers. Like [right now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149432/mark-trapp#qpage_1-anpage_2-qsort_newest-ansort_newest):

[image: No sort buttons on last page for 32 items]

[Also](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138677/david-andersson) when there is just 2 items in total, but that is hardly an issue:

[image: No sort buttons when only 2 items in total]