# Is imgur losing images?

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, imgur

Are there any missing images from [Imgur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur), and especially images that were uploaded using the editor (to the Stack Exchange [pro account](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/))? When did those images go missing?

For at least the past 20 hours, https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOc0U.jpg as used in [a question on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62063/add-navigation-buttons-to-browse-through-answers) shows a generated image claiming "*The image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available*". [Like](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FzOc0U.jpg):

```
GET /zOc0U.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: i.imgur.com

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: image/png 
Content-Length: 2609
Expires: Mon, 16 Jan 2012 10:50:29 GMT  
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
```

The author meanwhile has indicated he used the upload feature from the editor.

Note that after *refreshing* a page, [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) might not show the generated image either, eventually timing out. A *copy* of the generated image, just for future reference if this is ever fixed:

[image: Copy of the generated image]

(My Safari on a Mac times out after a refresh. That could be caused by the missing `Location` in the HTTP `301 Moved Permanently`; using Chrome or Firefox always seems to get me the generated image. I am not sure if the missing `Location` is an Imgur feature, but that's not the issue here. I have not tested the refresh with Internet Explorer.)

Comment: Are you sure this image wasn't uploaded to imgur manually? I do this myself when I use an external editor to write a post.

Comment: @marcog, I am not *sure*, but the author claims so in [the comments of the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62063/add-navigation-buttons-to-browse-through-answers#comment-148239). And given the earlier comments about the JPG format, I guess it's indeed true.

Comment: And, @marcog, despite the current problems: for important images please consider using the Stack Exchange account? [Link rot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71529/can-we-have-some-tools-to-handle-link-rot) and image rot are not too nice...

Comment: I wasn't aware of the implications, so for sure I will do so in future. I don't suppose there's any way to use the SE account without going through the built-in upload feature? I also wonder if it would be a worthwhile feature to automatically replace linked images with self-uploaded images (I hope that makes sense)?

Comment: As for using the SE account, @marcog: I don't know, but I've always been wondered a bit about imgur not using the `Referer` headers when images are requested by a browser. That is, of course, nice for folks who use the data dump, but would (*might*) make it an easy target for abuse... I don't know if there's any feature request for automatic conversion yet (there is some request for [Can we have some tools to handle link rot?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71529/can-we-have-some-tools-to-handle-link-rot) but that is not about the time an new/edited post is submitted).

Comment: **NOTE**: when still missing images, see [Images manually uploaded to Imgur are not displaying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95732/images-manually-uploaded-to-imgur-are-not-displaying/95734#95734)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is Alan from Imgur. I just wanted to let everyone know that the issue has been resolved and all of the missing images should be working again. Please let me know if anyone runs into any more issues with Imgur; I'd be happy to help.

Comment: And as an aside: note the remark on the missing `Location` in the `301 Moved`. If you want Safari (on a Mac) to show the generated message after a page refresh too, then I assume you might need such `Location` — even though this might also be a bug in Safari; I don't know the specs.

Comment: Mental note: [time to talk to the boss' boss about throwing these guys some business].

Comment: @Arjan: yeah, sorry, I'd redraw it nicer, but the feature-request itself seems flawed anyway...

Comment: @Hans Many years ago we found one of our carriers playing a game with our SLA window: they dropped some links intentionally just to brag about how quick they recover from failure :D. Not this case I bet, but I learned a lesson: "better than fast recoveries are the unneeded ones"

Comment: @Alan, my current ISP is blocking imgur images. Are you guys aware of that?

Comment: @Alan [It appears to be happening again.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20022/mid-90s-post-apocalyptic-action-game/20024#20024)

Comment: @Alan, there are two instances for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669073/force-scientific-notation-in-tick-labels-of-listloglogplot/5677438) alone.

Comment: @Alan, The third pic [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62266/tag-box-on-top-of-questions-page-doesnt-show-markdown-backticks) is missing.

Comment: @Alan: You should be aware that the third picture in this question is missing.

Comment: @Alan , right now, the following links don't work:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/ndf3W.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/zX4Ig.png
(they are used here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25641247/3885376 )

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/nm1MbxH.gif

Comment: Hello, is the problem back? I cannot display the images on this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72662/trying-to-make-glossy-volume-shapes

Comment: @ Alan - if you're still at the same job all these years later, could you have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314028/276027