# User profile activity filtering has no pagination to last page

Tags: bug, status-completed, recent-activity, pagination

My badges: [Page One](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/89334/waiwai933?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_badges) shows no pagination, but [Page Two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/89334/waiwai933?tab=activity#apage_2-afilter_badges) does actually exist.

Grace Note's accepts (just as a random example): [Page Two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146126/grace-note?tab=activity#apage_2-afilter_accepts) shows pagination for `prev [1] [2]`, but surely there is a [Page Three](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146126/grace-note?tab=activity#apage_3-afilter_accepts) as well.

So: there is no paging button to the last page—if there are only two pages, the system thinks there's only one page and drops the paginator completely. This off-by-one (off-by-thirty?) bug is evident across all user activity tabs (including `all`).

[image: Page 3 showing pagination for page 1 and 2 only]

Comment: Oh, it does happen on Jeff's page: At the moment of writing this comment, you can't page through to the last 21 of his badges. I've just posted this myself, probably a duplicate: [Problem with paging through recent activity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85805/155585).

Comment: Ah, smells like (the resolved) [Question sorting controls disappear when there are either 1 or 2 questions on the last page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55108/question-sorting-controls-disappear-when-there-are-either-1-or-2-questions-on-the).

Comment: @Arjan: This one has a somewhat different stench; the last page is missing no matter how many entries it has.

Comment: @HendrikVogt not *quite* - prior to the fix, if you had an exact multiple of the page-size it would be right. Which gives away the exact nature of the bug ;p

Comment: @Marc: Oh my, you're more finnicky than I am, an I'm a mathematician `:-)` But you're right of course, and this was what I meant to write. Thanks a lot indeed for the bug fix!

Comment: @Hendrik I confess that maths was my route too. But I rarely use much of it now (except logic/reasoning, on a good day)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An off-by-one; fixed in next deploy.