# What does it mean when you are last in the badges list?

Tags: support, tags

I wonder what it means when you are listed last in a badge's user list.

What I *do* know, is that there is no user that reached the silver badge before you were viable for getting it.

What I do *not* know is, how do you find out whether there was no other user that was viable for getting the badge when you got the badge?

---

More elaborative explanation: Assuming that both you and another user are listed last at the user list for a tag badge, with you being last listed. There are two scenarios

- Both of you had 400 upvotes and 80 answers when tag badges were introduced in SO, so both of you immediately got the silver badge.
- You got the silver badge first before the other user was viable for getting it, and then the other user got it when he became viable for getting it.

I want to distinguish the two cases, so that I can accurately determine the conditions under what badges were given out.

Perhaps a way to do this is to compare the times users got the badge, and if the difference is only a few minutes, I could conclude that this is case one. But I wonder whether there is a more easy way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, just go to the "activity" tab in the user profile, click "badges" filter and see when that other user gained the badge. Do the same in your profile and you have your answer. :)

For example:
[image]

Comment: That won't work. If we had 500 points at the time silver badges were introduced some years ago, we would both get the silver badge at the same time, and the time displayed would perhaps differ by a second or such. The badges user list is already sorted by time, so I wouldn't need to go to the user pages to know who got the badge first physically (instead of logically, i.e by being the only one over 400 reps/80 answers).

Comment: @Johannes - I see. So maybe a query [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/) can produce what you're after?

Comment: +1 for pointing out the "badges" tab (or filter or whatever). However, it doesn't show all the badges if you have more than 30 - seems to be a bug in the paging.

Comment: Here's a link to the bug report: [User profile activity filtering has no pagination to last page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81634/155585). (This was the relevant piece of information in a now deleted discussion.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the badge lists for tags are ordered by the time it was acquired.  Which means that if you're listed last then you were the first to get it.  This is not documented nor promised to behave that way of course.

Comment: I've tried to state the question more clearly now.