# Links on user page are missing

Tags: bug, profile-page, pagination

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question sorting controls disappear when there are either 1 or 2 questions on the last page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55108/question-sorting-controls-disappear-when-there-are-either-1-or-2-questions-on-the)

Normal screen when I go to my user page on SO:

[image: Page has multiple items and sorting tabs]

Now in questions when I click 4 it shows following:

[image: Last page has 2 items and no sorting tabs]

The links for sorting questions are missing.... It happens only for 4th page in 2nd and 3rd page links are available.

Environment: Google chorme 10.0.648.204 on Windows XP SP 3.

Link to my user page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/559070/harry-joy#qpage_4-anpage_1-qsort_votes-ansort_votes

Comment: A pretty old and long-standing bug, [reported earlier here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55108/question-sorting-controls-disappear-when-there-are-either-1-or-2-questions-on-the). Please consider upvoting that report to help spur a resolution. ♪